# JQuery Mobile App - section of code that breaks the entire app

Tags: android, jquery, html

For whatever reason, this section of code breaks the entire app. The app should go back and forth between pages by the use of listviews, but this section of code breaks it.  Once I remove this section of code the app flows as is intended.  I cannot find an error with the code.  Anything that I might have missed?  Thanks

Here is the code:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="addbasic">

  <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    <h3>
      Addition Basics
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <!--<div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>-->

      <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="addtable1">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <p align="center"><b><font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">Step 1:</font></b>
              </p>
              <td align="center"><b><font color="#FF0000" face="Arial" size="3">Set A</font></b>
              </td>
              <td align="center"><b><font color="#0000FF" face="Arial" size="3">Set B</font></b>
              </td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
              <td align="center"><b><font face="Arial" size="3">How many<br />
                triangles are in <font color="#FF0000">Set A?</font>
                <br />
                (There are <font color="#FF0000">2</font>!)</font></b>
              </td>
              <td align="center"><b><font face="Arial" size="3">How many<br />
                triangles are in <font color="#0000FF">Set B?</font><br />
                (There are <font color="#0000FF">3</font>!)</font></b>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="center"><b><font face="Arial">
                <img alt="Set A: 2 triangles" src="img/add/add basic/seta.png" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 210px; height: 125px;" /></font></b>
              </td>

              <td align="center"><b><font face="Arial">
                <img alt="Set B: 3 triangles" src="img/add/add basic/setb.png" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 232px; height: 129px;" /></font></b>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <br />
      <hr >

      <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="addtable2">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <p align="center"><b><font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">Step 2:</font></b>
              </p>

              <p align="center"><b><font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">Now combine them into one set!</font></b>
              </p>

              <img alt="Combined sets" src="img/add/add basic/combined.png" />

            </tr>  

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <br />
      <hr >

      <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="addtable3">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <p align="center"><b><font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">Step 3:</font></b>
              </p>

              <p align="center"><b><font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">Count how many triangles are in the new set</font></b>
              </p>

              <img alt="Combined sets" src="img/add/add basic/combined.png" />

              <p align="center"><b><font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">
                There are <font color="purple">5</font> total!
              </p>

              <img alt="Combined sets" src="img/add/add basic/equation.png" />

            </tr>  

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <a href="#addition">Go to addition page</a>

    </div>

  <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer">
    <h1>Copyright 2015</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

EDIT* I dont know if this means anything, but I am using Sublime text and if I select the very last div here shown in the code it will show me that it connects the last div that shows:

```
<div align="center">
```

Not sure why it does this since I can select the approiate closing div for this block of code and also goes to this div.  Might be nothing, but selecting the last div show that

```
  <div data-role="page" id="addbasic">
```

is the opening div.

Answer (score 0):

In this section of the code:

```
<p align="center"><b><font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">
        There are <font color="purple">5</font> total!
</p>
```

There is an extra font tag that was not closed and that caused the error.